# Creating a project with Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Do I need to install virtualenv for every different django project that I make or should I just go straight to creating a virtualenv after I installed it in the first project?

Comment: The best practice is to create separate virtual environment for each project.

Comment: So i should install it in every project that I make?

Comment: well if you working on a testing project or some learning project then a common can do ,  but if you are working on full fledge one project then  better to create a seperate one

Comment: understood. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a separate virtual environment for each project. So that you can avoid python package dependency issues.

Answer (score 1):

So first try to understand the definition of Virtual environment," a self-contained directory tree". Now you can create different Virtual environments, What I prefer doing is using a virtual environment based on their uses, like if one virtual environment has all the basic requirments, i don't have to create another one.